# Including url in django template

Tags: python, django, html

I want to embed a url in django template which is returned from django view. Am getting no reverse match error.Find the files below,

1.global urls.py

```
url(r'^account/',include("accounts.urls" , namespace = "account")),
```

2.account app's urls.py

```
url(r'^confirm/$', views.confirm, name = "confirm"),
```

3.views.py

```
 hostname = "127.0.0.0:8000"
 user_details = {'link':'account:/account/confirm?activation_key=12234dfserr534vbgh','hostname':hostname}
 message =get_template('accounts/mails/confirm_mail.html').render(Context(user_details))
```

4.confirm_mail.html

```
<a href={{hostname}}{% url link %}>click</a>
```

How can I put the link in my template.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't have a URL named "link" in your urls.py, you just have "account:confirm".

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to create a dynamic url which am assigning to a varaiable link and I want to render it in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The link key you have in your dict is a strange mixture of namespace, template and querystring. The `url` tag only takes a URL name, which in this case is "account:confirm". The querystring needs to be added separately:

```
user_details = {'link': 'account:confirm', 'querystring': 'activation_key=12234dfserr534vbgh', 'hostname': hostname}

<a href="{{ hostname }}{% url link %}?{{ querystring }}">click</a>
```

Comment: Agreed. Note: I think you have a missing single quote in activation_key (at the beginning)